# Docker service update REST API returning 400 Bad Request

Tags: docker, api, rest, docker-swarm

I'm trying to query the [Docker Service REST API](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.40/#operation/ServiceUpdate), however I keep receiving a `400 Bad Request` response.

Here's my request:

```
curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock \
  http:/services/my_great_service
```

which returns

```
{
  "ID": "i5wa2p1jx1opyt94nldm1latj",
  "Version": {"Index":132186},
  "CreatedAt": "2020-11-03T23:59:57.534640547Z",
  "UpdatedAt": "2020-11-04T00:24:47.090939187Z",
  "Spec": {
    "Name": "my_great_service",
    "Labels": {
...
```

I believe this is telling me the `version` is `132186`, so my request to update the service is:

```
curl -X POST --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock \
  http:/services/my_great_service/update?version=132186
```

which returns:

```
400 Bad Request
mismatched Runtime and *Spec fields
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong with the version or methods to further troubleshoot what's bad about my request?